# Holding SQL Connection In Powershell Function

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I am attempting to hold a SQL connection in a function so that I can call that, rather then replicating the code each time. A user from here suggested it to a question I posted a while back. I am trying to replicate the process but I' getting the error:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

The code is as follows:

```
$server = "TEST"
$database = "Lookups"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database;")

function Execute-SQL ($query, $connection) {
$connection.Open();
$command = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection);
$command.ExecuteNonQuery();
$connection.Close();

}

$query = "TRUNCATE TABLE [Lookups].dbo.[client_lookup]"

Execute-SQL $query, $connection
```

Am I even close? Apologies in advance but I can't seem to find much written about this.

Please see the full error:

```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:6 char:1
> + $connection.Open();
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:8 char:1
> + $connection.Close();
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a simple syntax error. In Powershell, parameters are separated with spaces, not commas like a lot of other languages do.

Use proper syntax and it will work, like so:

`Execute-SQL $query $connection`

Comment: Excellent. Cannot believe it was that simple. Thank You.